# What is role of AWS eventbridge in a kafka consumer lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to understand the implementation flow while I'm designing the blueprint for one of our usecase. As per existing articles/blogs, AWS now supports self hosted kafka implementation for lambdas. Also there exists scheduled lambdas. But does anyone know where does eventbridge stands here?

Basically I want to trigger lambda everytime there's an event change in the topic it's subscribing too. So should the lambda act as a consumer that will listen to topics? If yes, since it's serverless, someone has to tell that there's a change. So will cloudwatch would be the one to do so?

Again if yes, does cloudwatch also needs to be acting as consumer and listen to topics?

Please help me understand, this might sound like an opinion question, but really nowhere I could find the correct answer.

P.S.- I know there's MSK and Kinesis, but it's recommended to used between lambda, eventbridge, sqs, sns, s3, etc only. The target is to read the data from topics and send out emails to recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lambda service manages the integration with Kafka itself. You will config how it interacts, but ultimately your function will receive an event just like any other integration and it will include the messages from Kafka.

Comment: Okay, but for that will the lambda keep triggering by itself or we need to trigger it manually @Mark Sailes? If it keeps listening it will be running always, but if not then after every 15 mins it will shut down, then how will it restart?

Comment: There are two separate parts to think of. The first is the Lambda service, with your configuration it will poll Kafka and deliver the events to the second part. Your Lambda function. The Lambda service is responsible for the polling so you don't need to worry about it in your function.  It will be managed for you.

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense now. Thanks! Lastly, when you say Lambda service which will pe polling the topic, is it different from traditional Lambda function that we deploy? Can you provide me a resource I can look into service more? I'm only aware of Lambda functions.

Comment: Its the same thing. I just want to make the difference that it's not something you manage. AWS will be managing it. You can read more here -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-msk.html

Comment: This doesn't really answer how lambda knows a Kafka event is ready to be delivered (which I understand is an internal AWS implementation, and can't be answered directly). But for the use case of a self managed Kafka cluster, that consumer will always need to be running, whereas MSK might be able to detect a message had been produced and actually trigger the lambda. So it's not truly serverless?

Comment: The poller is managed by AWS. Whether it's self-managed or MSK. Just like any application, it polls for new messages.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article, understood it now. So eventbridge is not required right? @MarkSailes